# The code does not work corectly when I use .toggle() method in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this problem, using toggle(). The thing is that when I use toggle instead of click the block slides away from the page after reload, that I can't even, well, toggle the block.
here is the code

If I use .click( ) instead - it works, but if I write "toggle", the block slides away as soon as I reload the page not giving me to toggle itself.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Email input page</title>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#newdiv').on('toggle', function() {
        $(this).css({
          'background': 'black',
          'color': 'white'
        });
      }, function() {
        $(this).css({
          'background': 'green',
          'color': 'red'
        });
        /!* Stuff to do every *even* time the element is clicked *!/
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input value="enter your email:" type="" name="" />

  <div id="newdiv">
    test div for test something
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `toggle(fn,fn)` was deprecated in 1.8 and then later removed 1.9

Answer (score 1):

I spotted two problems here:

1) You cannot have a script source and the script code under the same tag `<script></script>` 
I removed `<script src="js/scripts.js">` to  `<script>`

2) You can listen to toggle event on `<details>` not a `<div>`

I hope this will help you. 
See the snippet below:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <head>
 <html>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Email input page</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
       
        <script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#newdiv').on('toggle', function() {
        $(this).css({
            'background': 'black',
            'color': 'white'
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).css({
        'background': 'green',
        'color' : 'red'
        });/!* Stuff to do every *even* time the element is clicked *!/
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input value="enter your email:" type="" name=""/>

            <details id="newdiv">
        test div for test something
    </details>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, but that was not exactly what I wanted. I actually have my .js file separated from html, so it was just my mistace of combining the code into one to paste it here.

Comment: what I wanted was to toggle the bg and font colour several times, like I click once - the block paints black, click second time - the block is green, and so on. I could use the click even - black, click odd - green, but wanted to use the toggle method for that. it was not ment to hide some bar, just change its colour.

Comment: here is the other example, that doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
 Here is another example of code with toggle, that does not work. the thing is that it has to hide/show the form below the block "formHide", changing the text in it the block, but insted with method .toggle() written to code the block just hides on the reload not giving to toggle itself.


<!DOCTYPE HTML>

        <head>
     <html>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title>Email input page</title>
            <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

            <script type="text/javascript" >
    $('#formHide').toggle(function(){
            $('#my_form').fadeOut(10000);
            $(this).text('expand form');
        }, function () {
            $('#my_form').fadeIn(5000);
            $(this).text('colapse form');
        });
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="formHide">colapse form</div>

                    <form action="form.php" id="my_form">
                        <div id="bigform">
                            <fieldset>

                                <div id="div_form_ 1">
                                    <fieldset id="innerfieldset">
                                        <legend>addition options</legend>
                                        <p><strong>You need?</strong></p>
                                        <div id="format">
                                            <input type="checkbox" value="sh" name="dop_oprions" id="shlem" />
                                            <label for="shlem">Helm</label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" value="bag" name="dop_oprions" id="bag" />
                                            <label for="bag">Backpack</label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" value="od" name="dop_oprions" id="od" />
                                            <label for="od">Wear</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <p><strong>insurance</strong></p>
                                        <div id="radio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="inch_yes" value="yes" name="inch" />
                                            <label for="inch">Yes</label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="inch_no" value="no" name="inch" />
                                            <label for="inch">No</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="my_button" />
                                </div>

                                <div id="div_form_2">
                                    <span>Model:</span>
                                    <select name="moto" size="1" id="motoSelect">
                                        <option value="1">FIrst value(options)</option>
                                        <option value="2">Second value(options)</option>
                                        <option value="3">Third value(options)</option>
                                        <option value="4">Fourth value(options)</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span>Days:</span>
                                    <select name="days" size="1" id="daysSelect">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <p><strong>Your email:</strong></p>
                                    <input type="text" id="email" value="Example: you@site.ru" /> 
                                    <p><strong>Your desires:</strong></p>
                                    <textarea cols="45" rows="2" id="mytextarea"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```